# MySQL query sorting by date not performing as needed

Tags: mysql

I have this query where I am trying to list a number of locations (parks) in the order that they have news stories attached to them. Below is the query.

```
SELECT tpf_news.park_id, date, name
FROM tpf_news
INNER JOIN tpf_parks ON tpf_news.park_id = tpf_parks.park_id 
GROUP BY name ORDER BY date DESC
```

The inner join is just used to get the parks 'name' from the 'park_id'. I have used GROUP because some parks have more than one story attached to it and I only want each park showing once in the list. Because I have to group before ordering, it means the query is using the earliest date attached to a park not the most recent. So the ordering is wrong.

How do I alter this query so that each park will still only list once but will be sorted correctly by the most recent date down to oldest date.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `max(date)`

```
SELECT tpf_news.park_id, max(date), name
FROM tpf_news
INNER JOIN tpf_parks ON tpf_news.park_id = tpf_parks.park_id 
GROUP BY name 
ORDER BY max(date) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the earliest date associated with each park, you'll need to perform a [groupwise minimum](http://jan.kneschke.de/2007/2/15/groupwise-max/) on that column. Then your `ORDER BY` will work as you expect, because you  have the correct dates.

When you do a `GROUP BY` query like yours but don't specify an aggregate (such as `COUNT` or `MIN`) on a column in your select clause, MySQL chooses one of the rows to use its value. This is difficult to predict or control, so you'll need to use a groupwise maximum or minimum, as shown at the link above.